# I want to build user control system in flutterflow

Tags: flutterflow

how to build user profile control system  - user allow to show, hide, public, only me for certain information such contact detail etc.. in flutterflow?

i am developing an app in flutterflow, where I need to give control to user over their inforation - such as contact details, their physical address, or any other information that do not want to share with public,  - user can hide/show/ certain inforamation to public. user can hide or show their info right from their profile